# Unable to ssh push in pygit2

Tags: git, ssh, libgit2, pygit2

I am trying to push using ssh to a github repo using pygit2.
Here is the error I keep getting.
Can you point out the error?

```
>>> sshcred = repo_.pygit2.credentials.Keypair('avckp','id_rsa.pub','id_rsa','')
>>> remo2.credentials=sshcred
##  remo2 is a remote object for the repo
>>> remo2.url
u'https://github.com/avckp/sansa-pygit.git'
>>> remo2.push_url = remo2.url
>>> remo2.push('refs/heads/master')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pygit2/remote.py", line 301, in push
    check_error(err)
  File "pygit2/errors.py", line 57, in check_error
    raise GitError(message)
GitError: HTTP parser error: the on_headers_complete callback failed
```

Comment: Why do you assign `remo2.push_url` to itself?

Comment: that is a typo.
it is remo2.push_url = remo2.url

Comment: Thanks for pointing out.
Just did.

Comment: You are not trying to push via ssh, but HTTP.

Comment: ah. The push_url should be git@... right?

Comment: That's one way some ssh urls start, but you just have to look at the schema, which should be `ssh://` (or use the scp-style `user@host:path`). Furthermore, trying to authenticate as use `avckp` to GitHub won't succeed, as that's not a system user they have. The `git@` part you refer to is the username, which you're overriding with an unusable one in your example.

Answer (score 1):

The username in Keypair should be 'git', as [#428](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/issues/428) said.

It should be:

```
sshcred = repo_.pygit2.credentials.Keypair('git','/path/to/id_rsa.pub','/path/to/id_rsa','')
remo.crendentals = sshcred
```

Then try push again.