# How do i push to remote with pygit2?

Tags: python, pygit2

i want to clone a repository, change a file and push these changed file back to the origin branch.
I can clone the repo with

```
repo = pygit2.clone_repository(repo_url, local_dir, checkout_branch="test_it")
```

but what do i need to do now to push the changes to the remote? I want only commit the changes for one specific file, even if more files are changed.

Hope someone can help me. TIA

Answer (score 0):

First stage only `file_path`:

```
# stage 'file_path'
index = repository.index
index.add(file_path)
index.write()
```

Then do a commit:

```
# commit data
reference='refs/HEAD'
message = '...some commit message...'
tree = index.write_tree()
author = pygit2.Signature(user_name, user_mail)
commiter = pygit2.Signature(user_name, user_mail)
oid = repository.create_commit(reference, author, commiter, message, tree, [repository.head.get_object().hex])
```

and last push the repo as described in [Unable to ssh push in pygit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559529/unable-to-ssh-push-in-pygit2)